# How do I enable the 'auto fill' option for a property in VS 2005?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005, properties

How do I enable the 'auto fill' option for a property in VS 2005?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is correct, but you might be able to type prop [tab] [tab] to get the shell of a property to fill.

Comment: That worked in my class but not on my home version.  There must be an option that requires setting.